# Custom annotation does not work in method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created annotation to check permissions on the APIs. Annotation worked when placed in class or method. But when I use it for both class and method at the same time, the annotation placed on the method is ignored
Here is an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CustomAnnotation(permission="manageUser")
public class UserController {

    @CustomAnnotation(permission="updateUser")
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public UserDto getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now @CustomAnnotation(permission="updateUser") in the getUser() method will be ignored and only execute annation in class UserController
My custom code

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface CustomAuthorize {

    public String permission() default "";

    public String attribute() default "";
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomAnnotationAspect {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthorizationImpl authBean;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(customAuthorize) || @within(customAuthorize)")
    public void pointcutForCustomAnnotation(CustomAuthorize customAuthorize) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Around("pointcutForCustomAnnotation(customAuthorize)")
    public Object customAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomAuthorize customAuthorize) throws Throwable {
        if (Objects.isNull(customAuthorize)) {
            System.out.println("Call from method");
            // Check permission
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
        System.out.println("Call from class");
        ExpressionParser elParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        if (!customAuthorize.permission().isBlank()) {
            // check permission
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `CustomAnnotation`

Comment: I updated it in my question ^^.

Comment: Try,
@CustomAnnotation(permission="updateUser")
@CustomAuthorize
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public UserDto getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
    }